# PHP mail using postfix doesn't arrive

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

I'm using PHP5 with postfix for sending mail, using the mail() function
when i check the mail log, it says that the mail was sent.
it arrives if i'm sending to another user on the same machine (no network) but if i try to send to an email with a different domain (example@exampleDomain.com) for example i see in the log something like this

> temporarily deferred due to sending spam or virus

I understand this is because i dont have a domain name yet, what i want to know is, will it work fine once i get a domain and an e-mail @myDomain, or do i have to do some special configuration for it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ensuring mail delivery](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html) is just a bit more complex than *just* having a domain name and a valid sending address.  You'll want to set up DKIM and SenderID/SPF.

Comment: As well as blacklists, IP blocks, greylisting, etc... etc... etc... It's a miracle email works at all these days.

Comment: well postfix is famous because it works out-of-the-box